# Rails ActiveRecord intersect query with has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following models:

```
class Piece < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :instrument_pieces
     has_many :instruments, through: :instrument_pieces
end

class Instrument < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :pieces, through: :instrument_pieces
    has_many :instrument_pieces
end

class InstrumentPiece < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :instrument 
    belongs_to :piece
end
```

And I have the following query:

```
Piece
.joins(:instrument_pieces)   
.where(instrument_pieces: { instrument_id: search_params[:instruments] } )
.find_each(batch_size: 20) do |p|
```

Where `search_params[:instruments]` is an array. The problem with this query is that it will retrieve all pieces that have any of the instruments, so if `search_params[:instruments] = ["1","3"]`, the query will return pieces with an instrument association of either 1 or 3 or of both. I'd like the query to only return pieces whose instrument associations include both instruments 1 and 3. I've read through the docs, but I'm still not sure how this can be done...

Answer (score 2):

It seems like what I wanted was an intersection between the two queries, so what i ended up doing was:

```
queries = []
query = Piece.joins(:instruments)   
search_params[:instruments].each do |instrument|
    queries << query.where(instruments: {id: instrument})
end
sql_str = ""
queries.each_with_index do |query, i|
    sql_str += "#{query.to_sql}"
    sql_str += " INTERSECT " if i != queries.length - 1
end

Piece.find_by_sql(sql_str).each do |p|
```

Very ugly, but ActiveRecord doesn't support INTERSECT yet. Time to wait for ActiveRecord 5, I suppose.

Comment: Oh, I didn't assume that you mean the real `INTERSECT `, I've thought you just want to 'AND' the conditions. The `INTERSECT ` is definitely not supported by rails now. The code will probably look nicer if you just generate the SQL string without using ActiveRecord at all.

Comment: After 1 year from your post, I have met the same issue here, it took me 1 afternoon till I found your post.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42689938/filter-by-many-to-many-relationships/42691195#42691195

Answer (score 1):

You can use where clause chaining to achieve this. Try:

```
query = Piece.joins(:instrument_pieces)   
search_params[:instruments].each do |instrument|
  query = query.where(instrument_pieces: { instrument_id: instrument } )
end
query.find_each(batch_size: 20) do |p|
```

or another version

```
query = Piece.joins(:instruments)   
search_params[:instruments].each do |instrument|
  query = query.where(instrument_id: instrument)
end
query.find_each(batch_size: 20) do |p|
```

Comment: When used with multiple values in search_params[:instruments], this query returns nothing...

Comment: Do you actually have the pieces matching both instruments? You can inspect the resulting SQL code in the Rails.

Comment: Yup. I suspect the problem might be because an `instrument_pieces` object only has two fields, `:instrument_id` and `:piece_id` and this queries for an `instrument_pieces` object with an `:instrument_id` of both values. Is it possible to do an intersection of queries in this case?

Comment: Can you post the SQL from log generated by my code, pls?

Comment: `SELECT "pieces".* FROM "pieces" INNER JOIN "instrument_pieces" ON "instrument_pieces"."piece_id" = "pieces"."id" WHERE "instrument_pieces"."instrument_id" = $1 AND "instrument_pieces"."instrument_id" = $2  [["instrument_id", 5], ["instrument_id", 6]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation []> `

Comment: btw, try another query from the answer, while the SQL looks good for me.

Comment: Thanks for your help!