# How to write set-operation queries in ActiveRecord without writing INTERSECT, UNION, or EXCEPT in SQL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have a Rails app for managing volunteers and I'm looking for 'the Rails way' of writing a complex SQL query for filtering all of the volunteer records. I have the following models:

```
class Volunteer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :volunteer_skills
  has_many :skills, through: :volunteer_skills
  has_many :volunteer_lists
  has_many :lists, through: :volunteer_lists
end

class VolunteerSkill < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :volunteer
  belongs_to :skill
end

class VolunteerList < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :volunteer
  belongs_to :list
end
```

If `@lists` is an array of `List` IDs and `@skills` is an array of `Skill` IDs

1. I want to find all volunteers on ANY `@lists` WITHOUT ANY of `@skills`.
2. I want to find all volunteers on ANY `@lists` WITHOUT ALL of `@skills`.
3. I want to find all volunteers on ANY `@lists` WITH ANY of `@skills`.
4. I want to find all volunteers on ANY `@lists` WITH ALL of `@skills`.

After seeing this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33557338/rails-activerecord-intersect-query-with-has-many-association), I created a solution to this problem using `.find_by_sql`. When the query involves finding volunteers with ALL `@skills`, I construct an `INTERSECT` query. When the query involves finding volunteers with ANY `@skills`, I construct a `UNION` query. When the query involves finding volunteers WITHOUT `@skills`, I format the query with `EXCEPT`.

Unfortunately, this solution is not NEARLY as friendly as one that makes use of ActiveRecord. I'm pretty new to programming, but the problem I'm trying to solve seems fairly straightforward/common. Is there a better solution that makes use of ActiveRecord?

I'm very grateful for any ideas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do most of the work with ActiveRecord, although you still need to use some SQL fragments.

First, make a scope for all volunteers on any `@lists`:

```
class Volunteer < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :on_any_list -> lists { joins(:volunteer_list).where(volunteer_id: lists) }
end
```

Then add conditions for each of your skills criteria.

Volunteers with any `@skills` are easy:

```
on_any_list(@lists).joins(:volunteer_skills).where(skill_id: @skills).distinct
```

For volunteers with all `@skills`, you need to build a query:

```
query = on_any_list(@lists)
@skills.each do |skill|
  query = query.where("exists (select 1 from volunteer_skills vs " +
                      "where vs.volunteer_id = volunteers.id and skill_id = ?)", skill)
end
```

Unfortunately ActiveRecord's `not` doesn't let you construct the opposite queries of either of the above, so you need to do the skills-lacking queries from scratch.

Volunteers without all of `@skills`:

```
on_any_list(@lists).
  where("not exists (select 1 from volunteer_skills vs " +
        "where vs.volunteer_id = volunteers.id and skill_id in (?))", @skills)
```

And finally, the trickiest, volunteers without any of `@skills`:

```
on_any_list(@lists).
  joins("left join volunteer_skills vs on volunteers.id = vs.volunteer_id").
  where(skill_id: @skills)
  where("volunteer_skills.id is null").
  distinct
```

(There is [an AREL way to do the outer join](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28721187/634576), but I don't think it's easier.)

The diverse techniques needed to write and understand each of these makes me wonder whether, as a whole, they're really better than your SQL versions. At least the `on_any_lists` part works well.

Comment: Thanks so much Dave! I think a benefit of your solutions is that they allow for further chaining with ActiveRecord queries--which makes them much easier to work with on the whole.

Comment: Yes, that's the advantage of ActiveRecord in general. Otherwise I'd give up and use SQL more myself!