# Filter by many-to-many relationships

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have 2 table: `Post` and `Category` with a many-to-many relationships.(`categories_posts` is join table)

I have a categories id list `[2,5,7]`. How can i find posts which connects to all those categories ?

for example, if I have 2 categories: `food` and `english`, I need to find all posts that about `food` and in `english` language.

I've try this but it doesn't work. (`filters` is categories ids)

```
scope :filter_by_categories, -> filters {
  where(categories_posts_ids.contains filters)
}

has_many :categories_posts
has_many :categories, through: :categories_posts
```

Answer (score -1):

In Rails 5 you can do:
Post.left_joins(:categories).where('categories_id IN ?', ids)